# NetSuite: Attach a SalesRep and a receivable account to a customer record

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to update customers,
I am try to attach a salesrep and a receivablesAccount to the newly created customers.

When I use the following code, I encounter the following error:
*ReferenceError: "RecordRef" is not defined.*

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/currentRecord'],
    function(currentRecord) {
  function beforeSubmit(context) {
    var curRecord = context.newRecord;
    curRecord.salesrep = new RecordRef(){
      InternalId: "-5"
    };
    curRecord.receivablesAccount = new RecordRef(){
      ??? how to retrieve the id ?
    };
    try {
      log.debug('record created successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      log.error(e.name);
    }
  }
        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecordRef()` is something you would use if you were trying to connect to NetSuite via SOAP web services with C# or PHP.  With SuiteScript, you would use `.setValue()` to set these values.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define([],
  function () {
    function beforeSubmit(context) {
      var curRecord = context.newRecord;
      curRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'salesrep', value: -5 });
      curRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'receivablesaccount', value: 7 });
    }

    return {
      beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
    };
  }
);
```

To find the internal ID for your chart of accounts, navigate to `Home -> Set Preferences`, check the **Show Internal IDS** box, and click **Save**.  Then navigate to `Setup -> Accounting -> Chart of Accounts`.  You should be able to find the internal ID for the receivables account that you wish to use.

Also, the `N/currentRecord` module can only be used in client scripts and modules and should not be used in user event scripts.

Comment: thank you, it works fine except the salesrep: no error is thrown and no salesrep update is done. We are using Sales Team: do you think it is related? I have tried `curRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'CustomerSalesTeam', value: 1550 });` with no luck.

Comment: it works by using `curRecord.setSublistValue({"sublistId": "salesteam", "fieldId": "employee", "value": -5, "line": 0});`